# Maxwell Stress Tensor to calculate force in Electrowetting

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, tensor-calculus

I am a School student and investigating electrowetting on dielectric (EWOD) as a part of a project for my course. I would like to understand how the Maxwell stress tensor can be utilised to calculate the horizontal component of force acting on a water droplet. (Where this force is localised at the triple contact line and occurs when the water is under an applied voltage on a dielectric). In this setup there is no magnetic field acting on the system so the Maxwell stress tensor can be written as:
\begin{equation}
T_{ij}= \varepsilon_0 \varepsilon_d (E_iE_j - 1/2 \delta_{ij} E^2 )
\end{equation}
(where $\varepsilon_d$ is included as the dielectric constant of the dielectric material)

Following this link [1](https://www.utwente.nl/tnw/pcf/education/j.m.burgerscentrum_research_school_for_fluid_mechanics/jmbc_course_on_capillarity_driv/Articles/frieder_mugele/j_phys_cond_matt.pdf) (page 9) it is explained that integrating the Maxwell stress tensor along the normal to the surface gives the net force acting on the droplet (where there is no tangential component of the electric field on the water surface as the water is considered a perfect conductor.) Can anyone please tell me why integrating the Maxwell Stress Tensor along the normal gives net force and how this integration is actually carried out?

Also, how can the horizontal component of the Maxwell stress tensor be integrated to give the form 
\begin{equation}
F_x = \varepsilon_0 \varepsilon_d \frac{V^2}{2d}
\end{equation}
given that the net force acting on the water droplet is
\begin{equation}
 F_{net}= \int \int T_{ij} n_j dA 
\end{equation}
(where $n_j$ is the outward normal unit vector to the water surface).

Comment: The "why" comes from momentum conservation applied to electromagnetic fields. You can read about it in Jackson, chapter 6.